# qt MYSQL Connection on windows doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to connect to MYSQL Database running on windows , I am using Xampp 
I used this code to connect to database

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
db.setDatabaseName("opencart");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");
db.open();
```

it print the following error message

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

I also added QT+=sql and when I try to print the drivers :

```
qDebug()<<QSqlDatabase::drivers();//("QSQLITE")
```

how can I establish mysql database connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default only the Sqlite drivers are compiled.

Check your {QT_DIR}\plugins\sqldrivers folder.

If its not there just go to {QTDIR}\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql and do the usual qmake, nmake , nmake install.

You will need to copy the .dll to your application's directory or in a place that windows looks for dlls.

Comment: what are usual qmake, nmake ?? can you please be more sprcific

Comment: Assuming you have the Qt source code, you'd go into the folder I said.  Run qmake and then nmake to build the dll.  I don't want to be rude but you ought to know what qmake and nmake are.

Comment: none of these paths exists in my case ,I have C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\sqldrivers and it produces deprecated error

Comment: So go download the source of qt for your version, run configure with the MySQL option and then nmake.  You'll end up with the dll you need. It takes time to compile but it's worth it.